"Enable and ignore future errors" does not work
In Visual Studio 2022, whenever I click on an object in my c# code and choose the "Find All References" action (which works correctly, btw) I get a series of errors above my code windows that look like, "'WidenScopeProvider' encountered an error and has been disabled. Show Stack Trace." followed by two buttons: one labeled 'Enable' and the other 'Enable and ignore future errors'. (Other providers in the message could be something else like "ReverseBooleanProvider" or "MakeReadOnlyProvider")
I always choose 'Enable and ignore future errors.' But they just keep on showing up on a regular basis. How do I get this to stop? Everything seems to be working as expected, so why do I get these errors and how do I stop them, or correct the issue that causes them?

It appears that there was an issue with the CodeRush extension I had installed with my Visual Studio. The issue went away when I updated to the latest version of CodeRush (v24.1.5).
